# Numpy vectorized logic giving unexpected output

Tags: python, numpy

I could swear this should be returning three rows that meet the logic, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why only one is coming back.. Can someone please explain this?

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                 [2, 5, 6],
                 [7, 8, 9],
                 [4, 3, 4]])

target_sum = 7

x = (((data[:, 0] + data[:, 1])==target_sum) | data[:, 0] ==7)
matching_rows = data[x]

print(matching_rows)
```

My terminal says:

```
[[7 8 9]]
```

but surely it should say:

```
[[2 5 6]
 [4 3 4]
 [7 8 9]]
```

No?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
x = ((data[:, 0] + data[:, 1])==target_sum) | (data[:, 0] ==7)
```

Notice the parenthesis position.

As stated in [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations): *Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority, which is lower than that of any arithmetic*. That means `a | b == c` is evaluated as `(a | b) == c`, not `a | (b==c)`.